# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) when using react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using `react-bootstrap` in my `create-react-app` project.
It is using `react-router-dom` and `redux` for routing and state management.
I was adding new route `login` and new component for that page.
and I am having following error.

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `LoginPage`.
```

I have tried to change the component name from `Login` to `LoginPage` and file extension from `jsx` to `js`, but nothing worked.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class LoginPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
            <Form.Text className="text-muted">
              We'll never share your email with anyone else.
            </Form.Text>
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicChecbox">
            <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
          </Form.Group>
          <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LoginPage;
```

this is code of `LoginPage.jsx` file.

expected result: this should be working with no error.

packages:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.7.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chartist": "0.10.1",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "node-sass": "4.12.0",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.32.4",
    "react-chartist": "0.13.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-google-maps": "9.4.5",
    "react-notification-system": "0.2.17",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router": "5.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0",
    "react-toggle": "4.0.2",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.5"
  },
```

Comment: What line is the error at?

Comment: react-bootstrap element `Form` and `Button` in `LoginPage` is causing error.
when i try without them it works.

Comment: Try wrapping the whole component inside `<React.Fragment>`

Comment: @RohitKashayp, I have tried wrapping the `LoginPage` inside `<React.Fragment>`.
but I had same error.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved in `react-bootstrap` 1.0.0-beta.2. The version in your package.json is 0.32.4.

In this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/login-page-0mm2p), you see the component render properly (JS or JSX) but only when the minimum `react-bootstrap` version is 1.0.0-beta.2.

Update with:

```
npm i react-bootstrap@latest --save
```